# Higher-order moment of output of LTI system

Tags: linear-systems, gaussian, stochastic

Assume a very simple LTI system. Assume $x$ is white Gaussian i.i.d. with variance $\sigma^2$.

[image]

The output variance is straightforward to obtain. For example, for a continuous-time system:

$$\mbox{Var}(y) = \mathbb{E}(y^2) = \sigma^2 \int_0^{\infty}|H(s)|^2 \,\mathrm d s$$

However, I am interested in higher order moments, for example, $\mathbb{E}(y^4)$. How can this be obtained (is there a closed form solution in the first place)?

PS: Note that $\mathbb{E}(y^4)\neq\sigma^4 \int_0^{\infty}|H(s)|^4 \, \mathrm d s$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case of input process $\{X(t)\}$ being white *Gaussian* noise with two-sided power spectral density $\frac{N_0}{2}$, the output process $\{Y(t)\}$ is a strictly stationary zero-mean *Gaussian* process in which all the random variables have the same variance $\frac{N_0}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2 \,\mathrm df$ *almost* as you say.  But the key point here is that the $Y$'s are zero-mean *Gaussian* random variables with known variance, and it is known that if $Y \sim N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ then 
$$E[Y^n] = \begin{cases}\sigma_Y^n
\cdot (n-1)
\times  (n-3)
\times (n-5)\times  \cdots \times 3 \times 1, & n ~ \text{even},\\
0, & n ~ \text{odd}.\end{cases}$$

Now, if the input process is just *white noise* (not necessarily *Gaussian* white noise), then the output process is *not necessarily* Gaussian, and while the mean and variance are as specified above, we cannot say anything about the *distribution* of the $Y(t)$'s and cannot infer anything about the higher moments of the $Y(t)$'s the way we could for Gaussian output processes.

If the input process is a zero-mean WSS Gaussian process (which is also a strictly stationary process) but not necessarily a _white noise process, than $\{Y(t)\}$ is also a zero-mean WSS Gaussian process (and so strictly stationary too) with variance 
$$\sigma_Y^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S_X(f)|H)f)|^2 \,\mathrm df$$ where $S_X(f)$ is the power spectral density of the input process and so once again we are in business and can use $$E[Y^n] = \begin{cases}\sigma_Y^n
\cdot (n-1)
\times  (n-3)
\times (n-5)\times  \cdots \times 3 \times 1, & n ~ \text{even},\\
0, & n ~ \text{odd}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Why not mention that $X$ is also zero-mean? I am referring to the 1st sentence.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. I very specifically avoided making the statement that $\{X(t)\}$ is a zero-mean process but I will make the statement about $\{Y(t)\}$ more explicit.

Comment: If I may ask, why is $Y$ zero-mean if $X$ is not necessarily so?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo White Gaussian noise is a mythical beast _defined_ by its action: the noise at output of a LTI system with transfer function is a zero-mean Gaussian process with PSD proportional to $|H(f)|^2$.We _pretend_ that we can fit this observation into theory of WSS process by _imagining_ that the input process is a zero-mean Gaussian process with autocorrelation function $K\delta(t)$ but that is different from _asserting_ that the input process _has_ zero mean or that the random variables comprising the input process are Gaussian etc.